# I'm able to update the TableModel using setValueAt() but changes are not visible in the Table

Tags: swing, jtable, tablemodel

I'm able to update the TableModel using setValueAt() but changes are not visible in the Table
below is the code:

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JDialog;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class TableFTFEditDemo extends JPanel {
private boolean DEBUG = true;
JTable table;
MyTableModel tableModel=new MyTableModel();

public TableFTFEditDemo() {
    super(new GridLayout(1,0));

    table = new JTable(tableModel);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    //Set up stricter input validation for the integer column.
    table.setDefaultEditor(Integer.class,
                           new IntegerEditor(0, 100));

//If we didn't want this editor to be used for other
//Integer columns, we'd do this:
//table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor(
//  new IntegerEditor(0, 100));

    //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
    add(scrollPane);
}

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[] columnNames ;
    private Object[][] data; 
    MyTableModel(){
    columnNames=new String[] {"First Name","Last Name","Sport","# of Seaters","Vegetarian","blank"};
    data=new Object[][] {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
            "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false),"sdf"},
            {"John", "Doe",
            "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true),"reytry"},
            {"Sue", "Black",
            "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false),"wwttu"},
            {"Jane", "White",
            "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true),"yuiyio"},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
            "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false),"ertey"}
    };
}
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    /*
     * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
     * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
     * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
     * rather than a check box.
     */
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
        //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
        if (col < 2) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                               + " to " + value
                               + " (an instance of "
                               + value.getClass() + ")");
        }

        data[row][col] = value;
        this.fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);

        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("New value of data:");
            printDebugData();
        }
    }

    private void printDebugData() {
        int numRows = getRowCount();
        int numCols = getColumnCount();

        for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableFTFEditDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    TableFTFEditDemo newContentPane = new TableFTFEditDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
void runtable(){

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
            tableModel.setValueAt(new Integer(5),2,5); 
     ((AbstractTableModel)table.getModel()).fireTableCellUpdated(2,5);
        }
    });
}
 /** using this to call setValueAt from other classes*/
public void setValueAt1(Object value, int row, int col) {
     table.setValueAt(new Integer(5),row,col); 
     ((AbstractTableModel)table.getModel()).fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);   
    }
 }
```

PS: the code is taken frm oracle' example..i just want to knw how to reflect the changes made in tablemodel in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected, just you do not actually call `setValueAt()` on your model. Your runtable() method where you do is never invoked.

To verify, change `createAndShowGUI()` to return the `newContentPane` and use the following main:

```
    static TableFTFEditDemo instance;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            instance = createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            instance.tableModel.setValueAt(5, 2, 5);
        }
    });
}
```

[image: Screen shot]

After the programmed five second delay, the value in column 2 row five will change from "wwtu" into "5".

Comment: Thanx for replying.
Actually i'd be using setValueAt1() from other class for setting the values so main() is not gonna be invoked..is there any way to do that?

Comment: Well, any from anywhere, as long as you have a reference to the instance of the model. Only, if you are setting values from non Swing thread, do not forget to use invokeLater.

Comment: i m still confused..basically cause i'm using swing for the first time...can you paste you code here nd explain the invoking part.

Comment: i understood my mistake..thanx fr the help..really appreciate it :) :)